# How to read Neo4j responce array in php

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, graphaware

I'm trying to read a cypher return in my php code using GraphAware.

I've tried all found variant of return reading, but none of them works. The count of the array is 1, but when I try to echo the array's elements by index or in a loop, nothing is printed. But, the Neo4j browser returns a set of nodes by the query, so the query is valid.

Assuming we have one matching node:

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:mypassword@localhost:7687/db')
    ->build();

$check_1_node = "MATCH (b) WHERE b.name = '{$_POST['node1']}' OR b.name = '{$_POST['node2']}' RETURN b";

$check = $client->run($check_1_node);
$result = $check->getRecords();

if (count($result) == 1) {
    //Add second node and relation
    echo "There is really one node!"
    foreach ($result as $record) {
        echo $record->value();
        }
    //$add_second_node = "CREATE (b1 { name: '{$_POST['node2']}' })";
    //$client->run($add_second_node);
    }
```

The output is just:

```php
There is really one node!
```

If I call

```php
echo $result;
```

it claims the $result is an array:

```php
array
```

When trying to test a different approach with different functions something like this is thrown:

```php
Call to undefined method GraphAware\Bolt\Result\Result::getResultSet() in /home/paul/LitGraphs/create.php:14
```

I'm quite newbie for both php and Neo4j, so will appreciate every clue, including obvious.

Comment: put your response into var_dump() function and then check what's actually inside the response and you can also echo out if you json_encode($result). paste the output using any of the given function.

Comment: You're iterating over `$result` below, so it seems you expect it to be an actual array. You can use `var_dump` or `print_r` to properly output the content of `$record` inside that loop. That might help you get further.